# Number Theory- Find all incongruent integers of order $3^{18}$ modulo $2 \cdot 3^{20}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

### Find all incongruent integers of order $ 3^{18}$ modulo $2 \cdot 3^{20}$

I guess we use this formula
$$
\operatorname{ord}_n(a^k) = \frac{\operatorname{ord}_na}{\gcd(\operatorname{ord}_na,k)}  $$
But in this formula, we need to calculate Euler totient function of $2 \cdot 3^{20}$ and this number is so big. I don't know am I in the right direction or maybe even not close.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The group of units mod $2p^k$ is cyclic when $p$ is an odd prime.

Answer (score 0):

Since the $n = 2 \cdot 3^{20}$ is twice the power of an odd prime there exists a generator mod $n$ i.e. the number of order $\phi(n)$. Thus the numbers $g$, $\dots$, $g^{\phi(n)}$ are all different mod $n$ (remember that $\phi(n) = \phi(2) \cdot \phi(3^{20}) = \phi(2) \cdot \phi(3^{20}) = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3^{19} = 2 \cdot 3^{19}$). Moreover the order of $g^{k}$ mod $n$ will be the smallest $l$ such that $1=(g^{k})^{l} = g^{kl} \pmod{n}$ which is equivalent to $\phi(n) \mid kl$ because $g$ is the generator. Thus the order is just $\frac{\phi(n)}{GCD(k, \phi(n))}$. So we are looking for $k$ such that:
$$3^{18} = \frac{\phi(n)}{GCD(k, \phi(n))} = \frac{2 \cdot 3^{19}}{GCD(k, 2 \cdot 3^{19})}$$
Which is equivalent to $GCD(k, 2 \cdot 3^{19}) = 6$ and this is true if and only if $6 \mid k$ and $18 \nmid k$. Every eighteen numbers there are three multiples of $6$ and one multiple of $18$ and thus two numbers satisfying these requirements. Therefore exactly $\frac{1}{9}$ of all numbers have this property so the answer is:
$$2 \cdot 3^{18}$$